# register receiver on processing and android

Tags: android, processing

Trust me I have spent so much time searching for solutions but it doesnt seem to work for me. I have a really simple code where i would like my phone to discover bluetooth devices (yet). Here is the code (processing).

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import java.util.Set;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;

BluetoothAdapter BT = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BT.getBondedDevices();
BroadcastReceiver BCR = new BroadcastReceiver2();

void setup(){
    BT.enable(); 
    registerReceiver(BCR, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    if(!BT.isDiscovering()) BT.startDiscovery();
}

void draw(){
//
}

public class BroadcastReceiver2 extends BroadcastReceiver{

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    disDevName = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);
    print("Discovered: ");
    println(disDevName);
    if(disDevName == "XCHAN_PC") BTFound = true;
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
The function "registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)" does not exist
```

This is because PApplet has no registerReceiver method but instead, in Context. But I do not know how to get the context. I tried puting this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

and get the context out using this:

```
MainActivity act = new MainActivity();
con = act.getApplicationContext();
//...
//then this
con.registerReceiver(BCR, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
```

of it but it would say `"Null Context"`.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Where do you instantiate the class in which the function `setup` resides? Just pass a context derived class, i.e. an activity, to it in the constructor

Comment: You should be instantiating `Activity`'s by yourself

Comment: I have no idea how to do that I would need a quite detailed instruction.

Answer (score 0):

try this

In your Activity class:

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyClass myClass = null; //MyClass is your bluetooth utility class

    @Override
    public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onResume(savedInstanceState);
        // ...pass context
        myClass = new MyClass(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (myClass != null) {
            myClass.unregisterReceiver(this);
            myClass = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Now in your `MyClass` use:

```
    public class MyClass {

    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = null;

    public MyClass(Context context) {
        myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));
        context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED));
        context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED));
    }

    public void unregisterReceiver(Context context) {
        context.unregisterReceiver(this);
    }
}


    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work regardless of IDE. Your Android device is executing the code, not the IDE

Comment: what do u mean by Processing IDE?

Comment: I got multiple errors, one of which is "The method onResume(Bundle) of type mySketch.MyActivity must override or implement a supertype method"

Comment: try protected void onResume() instead of public

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 no luck

Comment: onResume() and onPause() are Activity's delegate method...why you are not using Android studio.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131819/discussion-between-rafsanahmad007-and-xchan).